# Is it safe to upgrade my web server from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, server, upgrade

Currently, im planing to move my site to Mediatemple. When installing an OS in the server, the latest Ubuntu version they show is 11.04. So, is it safe If I update it to 11.10 with "do-release-upgrade"? The server is new and I have nothing to loose yet!

**PS : I just found out why Mediatemple is not supporting Oneiric! Ubuntu 11.10 have a nasty bug where the upstart will take nearly 100% of your CPU! It effects some users who use virtual machines! It also doesn't reboot correctly!
I think I have to stick with Natty for now. I'll upgrade to 12.04 as soon as they release it!
Anyway, thanks for your answers!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more than safe but not really recommended.

Ubuntu 11.10 support will end in April 2013, this means that you will be then forced to upgrade again to some other version.

I think the best advice here will be wait for 12.04, then wait a couple of days more after the release, upgrade.

This way you guarantee that you will be running a version with support for 5 years after the release date. That is the most important fact you need to focus on when talking about servers.

Comment: Doesn't do-release-upgrade usually want to do one step at a time? So 11.04 to 12.04 will force him to go via 11.10 anyway?

Comment: I like to upgrade the server with new software at least per year and your correct... LTS is the best and the stable option... But, In my case, I have to stick with 11.04.. There's a different problem! See my question... I have edited it!

Comment: When 12.04 comes, I will might do a clean install by moving the site to a shared server temporarily! (Thats the same thing im doing now)

Comment: @BrunoPereira Actually I did the Upgrade and found out :) Its ok... I had nothing to loose... The server clean!

Comment: @BrunoPereira, well the original question contains "do-release-upgrade", and your answer says "wait for 12.04, then wait a couple of days, then *upgrade*".. so who's not mentioning it? ;)

Comment: @Caesium you got a point ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely - 11.10 is 4 months old now and very stable :)

Go for it. especially if you have nothing to lose on the server. If it doesn't work, what's the worst that happens, you have to install 11.04 again?

Additionally, 12.04 will be out in a couple of months and you'd be well advised to upgrade to that when the time comes as it will be a LTS release.

Comment: But in my case, there are some problems :D Just found out!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure if you upgrade to 11.10so that you can easily upgraded 12.04 lts
upgrading to 12.04 from 11.04 is difficult

Answer (score 0):

LTS is the safest option for web server, Ubuntu 10.04 should be your choice for now and go for 12.04 after one year of its release.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, but, it was probably down voted as it did not address the question. I think the question is how to properly or safely upgrade a server, regardless of if you are going from 10.04 -> 12.04 or 11.04 -> 11.10